# could not find image or family xxxxxxxxxxx in slurm gcp by terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, slurm

I have to create slurm cluster in GCP by terraform.
in file : terraform.tfvars , there are 3  blocks, controller_instance_confif, login_nodes and partition.
each among 3 blocks has source_image_family,source_image_project, source_image

I get the error message that

```
**could not find image or family xxxxxxxxxxx.**
```

I filled

```
    source_image_family={my_instance_templates_image}
    source_image_project={my_google_project_name}
    source_image=null
```

but I still get the error message that could not find image or family xxxxxxxxxxx.

Can anyone help me how to fill these 3 value?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `gcloud compute images list` [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list) to list available images.

The list includes `NAME`, `PROJECT`, and `FAMILY`.